# Djs interaction sending attachment separately from embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my message look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skitP.jpg), but as a result of `interaction.reply` I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxZ8z.jpg) instead.

Here is my code:

```js
fs.readdir("./pics", (error, files) => {
if (error) return console.log(error)
const num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)+1).toString();

const imagembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Some cute pic for you!")
.setColor("#980002")
.setFooter("Requested by " + interaction.member.user.tag);
interaction.reply({ embeds: [imagembed], files: [`./pics/${num}.jpg`]})
})
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Attaching images to embeds

Attaching images in embeds can be achieved using [`MessageEmbed.setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage). This  requires a valid link to picture.

### Attaching local images

Since [`MessageEmbed.setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) is the only way, to attach an image to an embed, you have to use some trickery. You have to send the image as file in your [`MessagePayload`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessagePayload) and add it to the embed.

```js
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed().setImage("attachment://image.png");
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed ], files: [`./path/to/image.png`] });
```

---

### Solution to your problem

For you, this would result in the following code:

```js
fs.readdir("./pics", (error, files) => {
  if (error) return console.log(error)
  const num = (Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length) + 1).toString();

  const imagembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Some cute pic for you!")
    .setColor("#980002")
    .setFooter("Requested by " + interaction.member.user.tag)
    .setImage(`attachment://${num}.jpg`);
  interaction.reply({ embeds: [imagembed], files: [`./pics/${num}.jpg`] })
})
```